# URL Rewrite Management "Custom" as Default Option

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I would like to make the "Custom" redirect option the default when creating URL Rewrites. Is that possible and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution would be to override core file `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Urlrewrite` and replace

```
return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit') . array_shift($modes);
```

with

```
return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit') . array_pop($modes);
```

in `getCreateUrl()`.

To do it the better way, create a module and listen for the event `core_layout_block_create_after`. Your observer method should look similar to the following. Maybe you want to additionally check for the request to limit the substitution to a certain action.

```
public function updateUrlrewriteButton (Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();

    if ( $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Urlrewrite )
    {
        $block->updateButton
        (
            'add',
            null,
            array
            (
                'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Add URL Rewrite'),
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $block->getUrl('*/*/edit') . 'id' .'\')',
                'class'     => 'add',
                'area'      => 'header',
                'sort_order'=> '10',
            )
        );
    }
}
```